# Finding the difference between one index and the remaining indices

Tags: matlab, performance, loops, vectorization

I have a vector:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
```

I want to find the difference between A(1) and the remaining indices:

```
A(1) = 1; 1 - A = [0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
```

I then want to continue to `A(2)` and until the end of the vector. So that I have the differences between all points from each other.

At the moment I use loops but it is very time consuming. How can I do this using vectorization techniques to improve performance?

I'm using MATLAB 2016a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using 2016a or earlier, you'll want to use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5];
>> bsxfun(@minus, A.', A)
ans =

   0  -1  -2  -3  -4
   1   0  -1  -2  -3
   2   1   0  -1  -2
   3   2   1   0  -1
   4   3   2   1   0
```

Starting in 2016b (or in Octave), you can take advantage of implicit expansion and do away with `bsxfun`:

```
>> A.' - A
ans =

   0  -1  -2  -3  -4
   1   0  -1  -2  -3
   2   1   0  -1  -2
   3   2   1   0  -1
   4   3   2   1   0
```